# From a container running on Docker for Windows, how can I access a port on the host?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm running a CentOS-based container on Docker for Windows and trying to connect to an http service running on port 8545 of my host environment.

I've tried this, attempting a variety of suspected host names and IP addresses:

`curl http://localhost:8545`

But the error message I get is "curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8545; Connection refused"

How should I figure out what IP Address to use? Is there anything I need to configure as far as allowing the port number to be accessed from inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is not working yet I think with Docker for Windows.
There is few things you can try. First you can add EXPOSE 'portnumber' in the dockerfile so the container will listen on this port. You can also use docker run with **-p 8545:8545**, it will map the port of the container and the host.

To get the Ip address of the container you can use:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" containername
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the docker command supplied returns <no value>

Comment: My fault, this is for a Windows Container I think. The best way is probably to run ifconfig in the container to get the actual IP address. Look at the command **docker exec**. You can run a shell or maybe even ifconfig.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the host using its ip but localhost/127.0.0.1 won't work (they will resolve to the Linux VM that is part of docker for windows). If you use the default network settings, your host should be reachable on 10.0.75.1 from your container